# divs grid displayed incorrectly in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

EDIT: I didn't  notice that I've put fixed width and height for .slot - it was 33.3333% initially. But IE7 rendered it "correctly" only with this fixed size (this page is iframed in a 600 x 600)

I'm trying to create sort of grid with divs that would fill whole page. After 2 days of googling an fighting IE 7 I'm finally here...

So the basic idea is 3x3 grid with external border and fixed spacing between cells. For this example vertical spacing is 2px and horizontal is 1px. Grid is filling the page.

Styles are:

```
html, body {
    width           : 100%;
    height          : 100%;
    padding         : 0;
    margin          : 0;
}

#root {
    height          : auto;
    display         : block;
    position        : absolute;
    bottom          : 0;
    top             : 0;
    left            : 0;
    right           : 0;    
    border          : 3px solid #000000;
    padding         : 2px 0px 0px 1px;
}

.slot {
    position        : relative;
    float           : left;
    padding         : 0;
    margin          : 0;
    width           : 33.3333%;
    height          : 33.3333%;
}

.block {
    height          : auto;
    display         : block;
    position        : absolute;
    bottom          : 0;
    top             : 0;
    left            : 0;
    right           : 0;    
    margin-right    : 1px;
    margin-bottom   : 2px;
    border          : 2px solid black;
}
```

And here's the markup:

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="slot">
            <div class="block">
                <p>Some text</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        ... 8 more times .slot div

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to make IE7 render it correctly?

Comment: If you want it to be 3x3 and to fill the page, then no brower will render that "correctly", except if your screen is square and you have a resolution of ~600px. Maybe you can put a screenshot of what you'd like to have and what's the problem in IE?

Comment: restored .slot width and height to initial values, my bad

Answer (score 0):

try this: add the css property `display:block` to the `.block` class. you need to fix the width of the `#root` div also because if the width is not fix the grid spread upto the available width.